# How much do dry beans expand when soaked?

Tags: beans

I've got four cups of dry pinto beans. What will be their volume after I let them soak overnight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically dry beans expand 2-3 times their original volume when soaked, depending on their age (fresher beans have more moisture left than older ones and expand less).
I usually put them in a large pot and cover them with at least 5-6cm of water above.

Answer (score 6):

It's closer to 3 to 4 times.  I actually measured mine, I make 6 pounds at a time and they swelled up (after cooking and draining leftover water) about 3.5 times.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an image of a dry pinto bean next to a pinto bean that I soaked for 8 hours. You can see that the soaked bean is about 3.5 times the size of the dry bean. 4 cups of dry beans will turn into ~12 cups of soaked beans.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I quick soaked 1 cup of black beans and wound up with almost 5 cups of them.

Answer (score 2):

I measured by volume, not weight. 3/4 cup of navy beans came out to just over 1 3/4 cups after cooking. After soaking them overnight, they were just about doubled. After cooking they were roughly 2.5 times the dried volume.